# How to make fire less "chunky"

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, smoke-simulation

I was working a little bit with fire simulation today. [image: fire image]

I used a particle system on some text that I converted into a mesh. I'm very satisfied with the smoke, but the fire looks kind of "chunky" with a chunk of fire for each particle.  I'm using a particle system with 200,000 particles over 85 frames.

I hate to infringe on anybody else's copyright (this picture is from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tfog5DqvfoU) link) but this guy got a very nice "non chunky" fire effect.
[image]

What parameters can I change so that I can achieve this effect?  (I'm using Cycles.)

Comment: I don't think that person is using a particle system to make the fire. There is a smoke simulation feature in Blender where the fire is actually converted to smoke and it looks much more realistic, and you don't need to use a particle system to do it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-IbKIdL1WQ

Comment: @Sanix25 Okay, cool! Is this possible in Cycles? From what I understand, using a particle system generally gives you more control over the fire. Is this not the case?

Comment: Using a particle system won't interact with the smoke. It won't experience vorticity. It's a living nightmare to try to make it photorealistic. If you use the fire setting that comes with the smoke simulation, it will easily allow you to make photorealistic fire, at the expense of certain controls like materials. However, it allows you to make extremely realistic fire and if you're trying to achieve photorealism, I would definitely recommend using it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeNPNOzIgTU

Comment: Also, It seems like you're trying to make the word "Fire" out of fire. I would recommend using a text object, extruding it, and assigning it an emissive material. After that you can set it as the emitter for smoke + fire (if the text disappears during the render just duplicate it before setting it as the smoke emitter, then just set 1 of the 2 identical objects as the emitter).